# Кроссплатформенная мобильная разработка

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7

Здравствуйте. 
Требуется написать мобильное приложение для трех мобильных платформ - Android, IOS, Windows. 
Какой framework лучше взять или стоить ли вообще использовать какие-либо framework'и? Может проще будет писать на нативных языках?
Что касаемо framework'ов, я склоняюсь к Qt. От приложения требуется работа с камерой, сетью и базой данных.

Comment: недавно наткнулся на статью с подобной тематикой, советую прочитать
http://habrahabr.ru/company/ubank/blog/230161/

Comment: я бы писал на нативных для общей базы данных

Comment: Также не упускайте из виду кроссплатформенный фреймворк от Adobe - PhoneGap. Разработка ведется на JS.

Comment: А что по поводу Qt?

Comment: @Sergey Kostin тупик там. Левых либ куча нужна.

Answer (score 1):

Луучше, конечно, на нативных языках. А так - используйте [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/).

Comment: А из бесплатных решении, что посоветуйте?

Comment: @Sergey Kostin http://phonegap.com/

Answer (score 0):

Бесплатный `codename one` - не подходит. Я пробовал. Он может дать только ссылку на нативный рекордер камеры. То есть, ваша программа во время съемки будет фактически открывать основную программу камеру и с неё снимать.

Вообще фрэймворки при работе с камерой - это очень большая вероятность риска. У нативных камер сильно варьируются методы, то есть разные камеры имеют разные ограничения на разрешения и частоту кадров. Если даже у вас получиться написать что-то кросс-платформенное, оно безусловно будет глючить и тормозить, ибо камера много ресурсов жрет.